# Make the character jump Based on Fps and Time

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a character based on Time and FPS.

What i need is make my character jump last for exactly 1 second.Right now i am using below code and it makes the character jump for 1 second.But problem is ..if the fps is 60 character moves 60 pixels , and if fps is 30 it moves only 30 pixels...How can i solve this..

I need character to move 60 pixels regardless fps and within 1 second.

```
//Below is the requestanimation frame loop
// which runs the loop 60 to 30 times per second , 
//  which vary according to browser.

    function jumpcheck()
    {
    if(isjump)
    {
    ball.posy -=1; //make the character move 10 px based on fps..


    window.timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
    isjump = false;
    }, 1000);
    }





    }
    }
```

note:request animation frame fps is something between 20 to 60 always changing.

Code as said by constantinous

```
var lastUpdate = Date.now();
function jumpcheck()
{
if(isjump)
{
speed = 1;
position = ball.posy;
var now = Date.now();
var dt = (now - lastUpdate) / 1000;
lastUpdate = now;
ball.posy = position + (speed * dt)

}
}
```

Comment: use the timestamp you get as a parameter to your callback in rAF to calculate delta time and then determine how much you need to move your character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For games it is usual to include the time since the last frame into your calculations. This time is usually called `dt` for delta-time. To calculate your new position you simply multiply the passed time with the current speed to get the new position. In pseudo-code this looks like this:

```
speed = ...
position = ...
dt = ...

position = position + (speed * dt)
```

Comment: dt is current timestamp ?

Comment: No, `dt` is the time since the last frame. You can calculate `dt` as the difference between two timestamps.

Comment: hey please check my edit..i modified code like you said..but its not working

Comment: You need to check what the actual units are. When you subtract two dates you actually get the difference in milliseconds. This might be a little high if your speed is in pixels per seconds. Usually the unit of `dt` is in seconds (or fractions thereof). With `var dt = (now - lastUpdate) / 1000;` you should get the difference as a `float`.
Also: you are subtracting the actual position from the balls position: `ball.posy =-position;`. But this should be the new actual position.

Comment: ok please check code .check my edit...its not jumping..please see http://photoapp.biz/test/node/jumptime/i.html ..press any key to jump